# Channel Entries & Relationships

Tags: channel-entries, relationships

I am trying to display a video and beneath it a series of related videos.

All video are currently separate entries in the video channel.

In another channel, "video_courses" I am using a relationship field to collate all video that belong to that course.

At present I can get the video to display and a list of related videos but it shows all videos and is not restricted to just the related videos.

How can I get the list to honour the relationship.

Current code:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="videos" limit="1"}

<h1>{title}</h1>
{exp:channel_videos:videos entry_id="{entry_id}" prefix="cv" limit="1"}

<section>
<div class="video-container">
{cv:embed_code}
</section>

{/exp:channel_videos:videos}
{/exp:channel:entries}



<ul id="carousel" class="elastislide-list">

{exp:channel:entries channel="video_courses" disable="categories|category-fields|member-data|pagination" dynamic="no"}
{related_videos}
{exp:channel_videos:videos prefix="cv" entry_id="{related_videos:entry_id}"}

<li><a href="{related_videos:title_permalink='videos/view'}" class="image"><img src="{cv:img_url_hd}{/exp:low_replace}" alt="image01" /><h2><span>{cv:title}</span></h2></a></li>

{/exp:channel_videos:videos}
{/related_videos}
{/exp:channel:entries}

  </ul>
```

Any help appreciated.

N

Comment: What version of EE are you running?

Comment: Expression Engine 2.7.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="videos" limit="1"}

    <h1>{title}</h1>

    {exp:channel_videos:videos entry_id="{entry_id}" prefix="cv" limit="1"}
    <section>
        <div class="video-container">
            {cv:embed_code}
        </div>
    </section>
    {/exp:channel_videos:videos}

    <ul id="carousel" class="elastislide-list">
    {parents channel="video_courses" field="related_videos"}
        {parents:related_videos entry_id="not {entry_id}"}  
            {exp:channel_videos:videos prefix="cv" entry_id="{parents:related_videos:entry_id}"}
            <li>
            <a href="{cv:title_permalink='videos/view'}" class="image">
                <img src="{cv:img_url_hd}" alt="" />
                <h2><span>{cv:title}</span></h2>
            </a>
            </li>
            {/exp:channel_videos:videos}
        {/parents:related_videos}
    {/parents}
    </ul>

{/exp:channel:entries}
```

You may have to experiment with prefixes inside of the Channel Videos loop, not sure if you might need `parents:related_videos` prefixes inside of it - but this should get you most of the way.